# Can i use fgetc() or fputc() in a binary file?

Tags: c, fwrite, fread, fgetc

I am creating an archive program in C, and i want it to save files i provide, list and extract them. 
I had many issues because i used a text file for saving, and it is not the best choice if i want to process binary files like music or photos, because when i extract them, they are not executed correctly (they are corrupted).
In order to solve this problem, i wanted to create a binary archive file.

Code for file writing (on extraction) is the following:

```
void scriviFile(const char * arrivo)                                //scrive i file creati in precedenza
{
    FILE * partenza;
    FILE * target;
    int c;
    int spazio = 'a';
    int i = 0;
    int pos;
    char * path;
    path = collegaSlash(getcwd(NULL, 0), nome);
    partenza = fopen(path, "rb");
    fseek(partenza, inizio, SEEK_SET);
    target = fopen(arrivo, "wb");                                           //apro il file
    if (target) {                                                               //se è aperto
        while ((c = fgetc(partenza)) != EOF && ftell(partenza)<=fine-10) {                                  //e il carattere preso non eccede la fine del file
            fputc(c, target);
            fputc(c, stdout);
            pos = ftell(partenza);
            if(pos==fine)
            {
                break;
            }
                                                                            //scrivo lo stesso carattere in out (file in uscita)
        }                                                                   //

        fclose(target);                                                     //chiudo il file
        fclose(partenza);
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("errore di scrittura del file \n");
    }

}
```

Since i need binary files to be extracted correctly, can i use code i wrote above, or do i have to change all `fgetc()` and `fputc()` functions with `fread()` and `fwrite()`?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you should change, or you might spend a considerable time with debugger to discover that your fget got some invalid value and created havoc

Comment: Either there is no problem when performing read write one letter to open a binary file.

Comment: @abasu What on Earth are you talking about? I see no problem with the use of `fgetc` here. Stop misdiagnosing. I do see usage of several variables which aren't declared. For this reason, we can't help AndreaGottardi with this code. AndreaGottardi: Create a minimal, compilable testcase to write the information from a structure (which isn't necessarily a `struct`) to a file. Then create a minimal, compilable testcase to read the information back from the file into a structure. Provide both of them here, but ONLY if they actually compile... Ask a question about something you don't understand...

Comment: Those who use the fgetpos(fsetpos) than ftell(fseek) might be better in the case of dealing with large files.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I know it doesn't compile, it's not the entire program. It was only an example function for better explaining. I asked on StackOverflow why this program didn't extract files, and someone answered me saying it's a problem regarding binary files and text files.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, yes, my mistake, i should have written in context to the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using [`fgetc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) and [`fputc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fputc) as you can see from the man page descriptions these function:

> fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.
>
> fputc() writes the character c, cast to an unsigned char, to stream.

A character, in C, is defined by the standard to always be exactly 1 byte (8 bits), this means when you use `fxxxc()` on a file you'll get 1 byte (that just happens to be a character in a text file).

If you extract and rebuild a binary file, byte by byte, you'll get an exact duplicate. So no, there is no issues with using `fgetc()` and `fputc()` on a binary file type. You can always prove this to yourself with a simple example program... for example:

```
int main()
{
    FILE * fptr = fopen("small_pic.jpg", "rb");  // open existing binary picture
    char buffer[10000] = {0}; // the pic is 6kb or so, so 10k bytes will hold it
    FILE * fptr2 = fopen("new_small_pic.jpg", "wb"); // open a new binary file 
                                                       // for our copy of the pic
    unsigned long fileLen;
    unsigned long counter;

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(fptr);      // get the exact size of the pic
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for(counter=0; counter<fileLen; counter++)
        fputc(fgetc(fptr),fptr2);  // read each byte of the small_pic.jpg and make
                                           // a new pic from it

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fptr2);
return 0;
}
```

end result: we have two of the exact same images, because `fgetc()` and `fputc()` can be used on binary files.

Comment: Hey man great answer. Quick question: do the initialization brackets in your line with `char buffer[10000] = {0};` initialize each element in the array to a value of 0?

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating an archive program in C, and i want it to save files i
>   provide, list and extract them.  I had many issues because i used a
>   text file for saving, and it is not the best choice if i want to
>   process binary files like music or photos, because when i extract
>   them, they are not executed correctly (they are corrupted). In order
>   to solve this problem, i wanted to create a binary archive file.
>
> --SNIP--
>
> Since i need binary files to be extracted correctly, can i use code i
>   wrote above, or do i have to change all fgetc() and fputc() functions
>   with fread() and fwrite()?

You can use the code you wrote above when working in binary mode. It's got nothing to do with `fgetc`, `fputc`, `fread` and `fwrite`. The reason this function won't work particularly well when working in text mode is that `ftell` isn't guaranteed to useful for anything other than `fseek`ing back to that location, hence the code `ftell(partenza)<=fine-10` isn't particularly suitable when working with files open in text mode. By refactoring your code, you can remove `ftell` and work with files larger than 4GB as a result... but that shouldn't be the only reason to refactor this code.